# Submitting JSON struct to MailChimp API via HTML form + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, mailchimp

Appreciate your help on what I'm sure is a real basic head-slapper. I'm setting up a simple web front-end so that I can check if an email address is already a subscriber to an existing MailChimp list. For now I'd like to just use basic HTML & JavaScript.

My MailChimp API Key checks out, and I can run queries that only require string data, but the relevant API call requires a struct for email address(es), and I keep getting an error in any variation of the code below. I've gone as far as installing node.js and just running that from the command line and the query does work with the same data, so I'm sure I'm just *this* close, but need your help to get over the hump.

Here is the relevant snippet of the script and form. As written, I receive the following error message in reply: Validation error: {\"email\":\"Please enter a struct\/associative array\"}"}

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function collectAndSubmit() {
        var emailAddy = document.getElementById("emailAddy").value;
        var JSONemail = {"email":
                            {
                                "email": emailAddy
                            }
                        };
        document.getElementById("email").value = JSONemail;
        document.getElementById("apikey").value ="M*Y*A*P*I*K*E*Y"
        document.testform.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/helper/lists-for-email" method="post" name="testform">
    Email Address: <input type="text" id="emailAddy" name="emailAddy" />
    <input type="hidden" id="apikey" name="apikey" />
    <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" />
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Check Email" onclick="collectAndSubmit()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The corrected/functioning code fragment is reduced quite a bit, since the email data can now be simply passed in directly from the form instead of being assembled in javascript. Here is the corrected input form entry:

    Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email[email]" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your form is incorrect. You can take a look at their [documentation](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/helper/lists-for-email.php). You have to setup what they call an `email struct` which is really an array. Your email input attribute should look like `<input type="text" id="email" name="email[email]">`.

Notice the `email[email]` it will make the data look like `"email": {"email": "input value"}`

Also if your api key is supposed to be a secret then placing it hidden in the html form is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks so much -- that was the issue; I've been reading their docs, I just couldn't figure out how to pass the struct. I'll update the code fragment in the original post with the corrected version.

If you can spare another few moments for a follow-up, you mentioned that placing the api key, which is indeed supposed to be private, as a hidden field isn't a good idea, and I definitely agree. What is the best alternative in this basic setup, or so I really need to handle this on the server side in some fashion?

Comment: @Bret yes, if the api key is to be secret it must live on the server side. So your server side language will create the api call and your form just submits to your server.